# Calculating Pre and Post Market Volume in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

i need the cumulative Sum of both, the pre and the post market Volume seperated to show it in my indicator.

But i have a hard time so far.

```
t = time(timeframe.period, "0930-1600")
tpre = time(timeframe.period, "0000-0929")
bool is_ext_session = false
if na(t)
    is_ext_session := true
bool is_pre_session = true
if na(tpre)
    is_pre_session := false

// float last_close/last_ext_close: close value of last regular/extended session


var float last_close = na
var float last_ext_close = na

if not is_ext_session[1] and is_ext_session
    last_close := close[1]

if is_ext_session[1] and not is_ext_session
    last_ext_close := close[1]
    
// float prevol: volume of pre market session

var float prevol = na

if not is_pre_session[1] and is_pre_session
    prevol := 0

if is_pre_session
    prevol := prevol + volume
```

this script should calculate all the volume between the cash session from 09.30 - 16.00 ?
But it gives me different values if go now (after the cash session started) on different timeframes.

also i would need separate values for the Pre and the POST Session.

Thanks for everybodywho can help